# Where can I permanently set java heap size on Windows pc?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I recently downloaded the latest Java 1.6 JDK. I'm using VisualVM which came with the SDK to test/monitor my webapp (using Tomcat server) on my local pc. I'm running Windows XP.

**Where are the parameters located for setting the min. and max. java heap size?** VisualVM indicates that the max. heap is at about 256mb. I looked in the server.xml file for Tomcat, but didn't find any settings in there.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the JAVA_OPTS environment variable for dealing with java heap size.
This variable can be added as a environment variable as well as you can define a configuration line in the `startup.bat` file.

Add the following line in the `startup.bat` file.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
```

You can add this as environment variable as said.

Comment: Are you sure it should be `server.xml` file? It should be some file where you run JVM (see matt b answer).

Comment: ouch.. sorry about that. I have edited the answer with correct file name. It should be startup.bat

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I just updated the startup.bat file and I started VisualVM...the changes have taken effect.

Comment: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
You should look for these values and find out what they do. As you see i have used maximum and minimum to 512m. But this does not be the case always. You may want to change these values.

Answer (score 3):

These parameters are passed to JVM via command line: -Xms and -Xmx
For more information run java -X.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to place these settings is in `setenv.bat` or `setenv.sh` in the `bin` folder. [Take a look at a recent SO question on the same topic which has excellent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progra).