# Adding java_opts params in Tomcat 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, centos, tomcat6, centos5

I have a requirement to add -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD in Tomcat to start an application.
Can any one point exactly where to add this parameter? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you plan to start Tomcat.  Tomcat itself wants to be run a shell script that's typically located at $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh (there's an equivalent .bat file for windows).  Inside of that file it describes what tomcat expects for an environment.  If you want to get your -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD system property into the startup of Tomcat, I think you just figure out how to get it set up in the environment as JAVA_OPTS and you are on your way.

If you are desperate and want to avoid setting up the environment, I suppose that you could edit catalina.sh directly.

The environment variable sequence looks like...

1. from a command shell, change to the directory where tomcat
   is deployed
2. from a command shell, change to the "bin" directory under tomcat
3. from a command shell, set the JAVA_OPTS evironment variable like "JAVA_OPTS=-DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD"
4. from a command shell, start tomcat like "./startup.sh"

The output will look like...

```
bobk-mbp:~ bobk$ cd work/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/
bobk-mbp:apache-tomcat-6.0.35 bobk$ cd bin
bobk-mbp:bin bobk$ JAVA_OPTS=-DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD
bobk-mbp:bin bobk$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/bobk/work/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/bobk/work/apache-tomcat-6.0.35
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/bobk/work/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/bobk/work/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

Comment: Half of the things you said was way over my head :D ... I think I will go for a desperation stuff. So how and where I have to add this param in Catalina.sh?
And after that can you explain me of how to set it up in the environment as CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS, so that I can be on my way ??? :)

Comment: JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD"

added that right under the #!/bin/sh should probabaly do the trick.

Comment: I really don't endorse this solution, though.  The correct way is to get the environment variable set up.  It is equally simple.  Are you windows or unix?

Comment: How are you running Tomcat?  From a command line, you are typing in something like "./startup.sh" and shutting it down with something like "./shutdown.sh".  Right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5675/discussion-between-bob-kuhar-and-brat-rosm)

Answer (score 3):

The simple and preferred way to set environment variables for Tomcat is via the `bin/setenv.sh` script.  See this: [How to tune Tomcat 5.5 JVM Memory settings without using the configuration program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr)

Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=setenv.sh

Comment: How about in Tomcat 6? Is it the same?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Also in Tomcat 7.