# Deploying JAX-WS webapp in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, tomcat7, jax-ws-customization

I am developing simple JAX-WS webservice. I am creating WAR file using ANT build script. The file when deployed to Tomcat 7 server, throws following exception and there is deployment error as follows.

JAXB 2.1 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from jar:file:/D:/DreamSoln/Server/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/webapps/WebserviceDemo/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.2 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader.

I have JDK 1.6 installed, I tried endorsed mechanism i.e. I created lib/endorsed directory and copied jaxb-api.jar and jaxws-api.jar in it. But still it does not work.

Do I need to remove jaxb-api.jar and jaxws-api.jar from WEB-INF/lib of my web-app?

What else needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are not endorsing correctly the tomcat lib. The folder `lib/endorsed` was used in previous version of tomcat (like Tomcat 5.5 if I remembered correctly) but in the new ones (Tomcat 6 and afterwards) the endorsed lib is usually at `<TOMCAT_HOME>/endorsed` (if it does not exist, you have to create it).

Actually, tomcat use the system property `java.endorsed.dirs` to define the endorsed folder location. So please check this value in your tomcat installation.

How to check this? Printing this property in any servlet/listener that you have in your application.

**Example** Using a context listener (inspired from [this blog](http://sajidmoinuddin.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/troubleshooting-tomcat-deployment-problem-for-jaxws-2-2-application-the-sherlock-holmes-way/))

```
public class WebappLoadListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n ENDORSED DIR: " +System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));      
    }
}
```

Hoping it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read the java.endorsed.dir property using method you suggested. But it gives me output as : [my-jre-home]/lib and not the [tomcat-home]/lib.

Comment: I observed that, its happening due to difference in JRE and Tomcat versions. I am using JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 7. I installed JDK 7 and it works fine with that.

Comment: When using the JDK 7 you are using the lasted version of JAXB (this is why is working). But if you still need to endorse your tomcat you need to put your libs in the `java.endorsed.dirs`. NOTE: Remember that you can change/set this property in the `catalina.sh`.

Comment: Would u advise how can i change and set these properties in Tomcat? and what version it should point to?

Comment: You need to set the value in the `JAVA_OPTS`. Please check this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424804/adding-java-opts-params-in-tomcat-6

Comment: Regarding the JAXB version, if you make it work with Java 7, you should endorse your tomcat+java6 to use the JAXB version included in the Java7. Check this to know which version is included in each Java Release: http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should remove these from the webapp once they are in the endorsed dir.

If you try the Java EE version of Tomcat, [TomEE Plus](http://tomee.apache.org), JAX-WS support is already integrated and JAXB 2.2 is in the endorsed dir.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 does NOT support JAX-WS out of box. To enable JAX-WS on Tomcat you need

1. to include at least "catalina-ws.jar" in Tomcat's lib (not necessarly under "endorsed"!).

"catalina-ws.jar" should be downloaded as "Tomcat extras", and it is not included in TC7's default download archive.

1. Include the "JAX-WS RI" libs in your web applications lib.

just try google "The Next Milestone: JAX-WS Web Service on Tomcat and JBoss", you would find more information about this topic.

(However for a Java EE container like JBoss 7, all libs are there already. )