# How to increase JVM memory allocation in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tune Tomcat 5.5 JVM Memory settings without using the configuration program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr)

I had a job hang in Tomcat 6.0.26 earlier and I suspect that I might need to increase the memory allocation the server is using. I have to admit though, I can find nothing in the logs to support this suspicion, but everything has worked to date and since the server was restarted.

The platform is Windows 7 64-bit and from what I can tell I need to amend variable:

> JAVA_OPTS

In file

> catalina.bat

The current server usage of the JVM is as follows:

> Free memory: 54.08 MB Total memory: 134.31 MB Max memory: 227.56 MB

So, am I right in thinking that adjusting JAVA_OPTS will adjust the JVM properties? Should I be changing JAVA_OPTS here and in this manner in catalina.bat?

```
if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" goto noJuliManager 
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager :noJuliManager 
set JAVA_OPTS=%    JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

rem ----- Execute The Requested Command
---------------------------------------
```

To double the current allocation?

Comment: have you searched around? There are a lot of questions and forum threads showing that

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Comment: Tomcat themselves recommend setting CATALINA_OPTS instead.