# How to increase max heap size in tomcat? catalina.sh has lots of references

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm running tomcat6, and I'm unclear if I need to set java_opts or CATALINA_OPTS?

Also, in catalina.sh there is allot of references to CATALINA_OPTS, so I'm not sure either where I should be modifying the heap size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set JAVA_OPTS or CATALINA_OPTS at the top of the catalina.sh file.  All the places a new value is set they ensure that it is appending to the existing values.

I prefer setting it in startup.sh instead of catalina.sh.  Setting it in catalina.sh would apply to the process started by shutdown command as well.

Comment: Those script will run `setenv.sh`(or `setenv.bat` on windows), it's usually better to create/edit those files and add the env. variables there, so you can keep your settings apart from the shipped scripts.

Comment: but what if it appends a setting that already exists? like Xmx?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to add custom things to Tomcat is by creating `<tomcat_home>/bin/setenv.sh` (on Unix) or `<tomcat_home>/bin/setenv.bat` (on Windows).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr) as an example.