# Failed to change Tomcat 5.5 JVM Memory settings (Linux server)

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, tomcat5.5

I want to increase the JVM memory settings for my Tomcat 5.5 instance (on Linux server with 1.8 gigs of memory).

Current JVM Status:
Free memory: 15.60 MB Total memory: 26.00 MB Max memory: 405.37 MB

I just can't get these settings to budge.  I tried the following:

1. Added the following statement to "setenv.sh" in /tomcat/bin:

   ```
   export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
   ```
2. Added the following statement to "setenv.sh" in /tomcat/bin:

   ```
   export CATALINA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
   ```
3. Added the following statement to "setenv.sh" in /tomcat/bin:

   ```
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -server"

   export JAVA_OPTS
   ```
4. Added the following statement to "catalina.sh" in /tomcat/bin:

   ```
   CATALINA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
   ```
5. Added the following statement to "catalina.sh" in /tomcat/bin:

   ```
   JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
   ```

NONE of these changes made any impact on the JVM settings.

I have exhausted all options identified from various support sites, including:
[How to tune Tomcat 5.5 JVM Memory settings without using the configuration program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr) and
http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/Adjusting+Memory+Settings+for+Tomcat

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *did* restart Tomcat after each change?  ;-)

Comment: For option 5, did you modify the existing JAVA_OPTS or did you add another?