# Set maximum heap space for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory

My `Java EE` application runs just fine on host server , but it uses a lot of heap space . allowed heap space is `64MB`. I am getting my hosting account suspended every time my app uses more then `64 MB` heap. I think the hosting provider has not set the max heap space for my app , that is why i am not getting the `outOfMemoryException` on reaching `>64MB`.

I have my own instance of tomcat, i can configure tomcat configurations.
My question is - how can i set the max allowed heap space for my tomcat instance so that it throws `outOfMemoryException` on reaching the limit ?
that way my hosting account will not get suspended.

here is the [catlina.bat](http://pastebin.com/WWGRXQ1h) and [catlina.sh](http://pastebin.com/MYT4B3Z5)

where do i have to make changes in these files ?

Comment: This has been discussed many times, for example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the heap space is simple as adding a command line switch to the JVM :

```
-Xmx2g
```

2g for 2Gb, if you want in megabyte : 512m ---> -Xmx512m

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable called **JAVA_OPTS**.

Add to it the argument `-Xmx1g`.

Replace: `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties"`

with: set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" -Xmx1g

Answer (score 1):

It is in setenv.sh which will be detected by catalina.sh:

JVM_ARGS="-Xmx64m"

Regards

Philippe