# Best way to increase heap size in catalina.bat file

Tags: tomcat, memory, memory-leaks, tomcat6, heap-size

I have tomcat 6 server on windows xp ,And I start tomcat through console i.e. using startup.bat.

AFAIK `catalina.bat` file is for windows so I am changing bat file for memory management.I don't have tomcat configuration window.

Now I want to increase its heap size so My question is should I extend the existing `JAVA_OPTS` in catalina.bat file i.e.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Or should I create new environment variable in catalina.bat file i.e.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

And Is this the correct way to do it?

Please guide.

and I am able to see current heap size in Probe but not able to see existing perm size so What is the default value for perm size?

Edit:

following parameters help any?

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you look in your installation's bin directory you will see catalina.sh or .bat scripts. If you look in these you will see that they run a setenv.sh or setenv.bat script respectively, if it exists, to set environment variables. The relevant environment variables are described in the comments at the top of catalina.sh/bat. To use them create, for example, a file $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh with contents

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx512m"
```

For Windows you will need, in setenv.bat, something like

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx768m
```

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr)

After you run `startup.bat`, you can easily confirm the correct settings have been applied provided you have turned `@echo` on somewhere in your `catatlina.bat` file (a good place could be immediately after `echo Using CLASSPATH:       "%CLASSPATH%"`):

[image]

Comment: Note from the Tomcat docs (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt): "__Note: Do not use JAVA_OPTS to specify memory limits. You do not need much
memory for a small process that is used to stop Tomcat. Those settings
belong to CATALINA_OPTS.__"

Answer (score 7):

increase heap size of tomcat for window add this file in  apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin

[image]

heap size can be changed based on Requirements.

```
  set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```