# Tomcat server crashes when doing the remote debugging with IntellijIdea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, out-of-memory, tomcat6

I do the remote `debugging` with `tomcat server` and `intellijidea`, after some time, the `tomcat server` **crashes** and **restarts** automatically. 
I recently only switched to `IntelliJIDEA`, before when i was using `Spring Tool Suite`, i didn't **encounter** any such scenario.
Anyone has **encountered** the same **issue**? or any **suggestions** on this?

The following is the **extract** of `log` from tomcat `catalina.out`.

```
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 | Heap
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |  def new generation   total 135360K, used 89556K [0x042f0000, 0x0d5d0000, 0x0ed90000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |   eden space 120320K,  74% used [0x042f0000, 0x09a5ad58, 0x0b870000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |   from space 15040K,   0% used [0x0c720000, 0x0c72a3f8, 0x0d5d0000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |   to   space 15040K,   0% used [0x0b870000, 0x0b870000, 0x0c720000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |  tenured generation   total 300224K, used 89569K [0x0ed90000, 0x212c0000, 0x242f0000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |    the space 300224K,  29% used [0x0ed90000, 0x14508780, 0x14508800, 0x212c0000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |  compacting perm gen  total 42496K, used 42446K [0x242f0000, 0x26c70000, 0x282f0000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 |    the space 42496K,  99% used [0x242f0000, 0x26c63ad8, 0x26c63c00, 0x26c70000)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 | No shared spaces configured.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:50 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/03/08 13:37:52 | 2016-03-08 13:37:52,692 [task-scheduler-3]  INFO BULKPAYMENT_LOGGER:89 - com.bcsis.g3.bulkpayment.stpcount.service.STPCountFileAdapterService:Temp cnt file deleted:true
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2016/03/08 13:37:53 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
STATUS | wrapper  | 2016/03/08 13:37:57 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/03/08 13:37:58 | Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2016/03/08 13:37:58 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.0) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
```

Comment: Is there any error output from IntelliJ?  For how long can use the debugger before this happens?

Comment: I think You need to expand your `heap` memory area size of Your `Tomcat`. coz problem with Your `jvm Heap` as it mentioned in Exception `log.

Comment: @mayuran  Try this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553350/best-way-to-increase-heap-size-in-catalina-bat-file

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Its crashes after around 5 mins.

Comment: @vikrant Kashyap: But how come it was working fine with eclipse/spring tool suite?

Comment: expand your jvm size then because `intelliJ IDEA ` is heavier tool than `eclipse` . So, It may consume your more memory than `eclipse` and your jvm size is limited. So try to expand your jvm Heap Size

Comment: @Mayuran see if it still works with STS? It may be that your code has simply changed since you last ran it in STS. IntelliJ doesn't (can't) impose any extra overhead on the debugger running in your remote jvm. Tomcat's jvm doesn't know if you're connecting with eclipse or idea -- it's all the same as far as it is concerned.