# How can I allocate more than 1 gb memory to tomcat on x64 windows7

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, permgen

Tomcat simply can`t start if I allocate more than 1 Gb memory, althoug I have 6 Gb free RAM space on the server.

Give me please any advice.
I have tomcat 6.0.35, grails 2.0.1, jdk 1.6.0_35

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? Are you running 64bit JVM? How much heap (`-Xmx`) did you allocated for JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i have 
JAVA_OPTS="-server -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -Xss64M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled" in catalina.bat (suggested by chrome). It seems that all works fine.
In the prev conf i had  only -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M options.

Than you guys for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you edit 
SET "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m" 
line in bin/catalina.bat?

Comment: yep. But if I allocate more than 1024 tomcat simply doesn`t start.

Comment: definately make sure that the jvm installation is 64 bit, though it should probably still work up to 2G of memory on a 32 bit jvm.

Comment: detailed description here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr)

Comment: My system is slackware and configuration of bin/setenv.sh is: JAVA_OPTS="-server -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -Xss64M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"