# WAR file is giving me out of memory error

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I am using tomcat 6 and the WAR file I have deployed is giving me out of memory error. I have installed tomcat6 using windows installer because of it I am unable to find any `catalina.bat` in `tomcat6.0\bin` folder where I can configure CATALINA_OPTS variable.

Comment: is it heap or permgen error?

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Its giving me an error "out of memory permgen".

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble setting CATALINA_OPTS in tomcat installation, you can set it as a environment variable in windows.

**UPDATE:**

If the previous method is not working then you can create a file, setenv.bat in bin directory of tomcat.

And in that file you can put the arguments like:

```
 set CATALINA_OPTS= "JVM Conditions here"
```

This did the trick for me, try it out.

Few links for your reference:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apache-tomcat-7-installation-on-windows.php

[How to tune Tomcat 5.5 JVM Memory settings without using the configuration program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr)

Comment: I have already set the CATALINA_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS as environment variable in windows. Still does not work for me.

Comment: @McTavish: You have to change your server memory settings using this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find the catalina.bat then edit your tomcat6w.exe and add

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

> You should change the “Xms” and “PermSize” value base on your server
>   capability.

Once done with editing simply Restart Tomcat.

Hope it helps!