# Spring and Hibernate application - performance issue on server

Tags: java, mysql, performance, tomcat6

I'm getting the following error on the server:

```
    Nov 25, 2013 2:01:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2245)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:242)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:216)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:208)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1504)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:712)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:942)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2117)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3927)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:648)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1107)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
```

I know that there's not too much info about the error message, but that's all what I've got from Tomcat. 
Java has 256MB heap space.

Do you have any idea what can cause that error?

Comment: may be you are fetching  a huge amount of data, Can you run the same query on database and check rows count and data.

Comment: There are about one million reasons why your application requires too much memory! Without any hint we will not be able to tell you anything!

Comment: How to increase the tomact memory settings explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286007/how-to-tune-tomcat-5-5-jvm-memory-settings-without-using-the-configuration-progr